# Line backgrounds stick togerther

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, styles, headers

I'm trying to color the background of some of my headers, but when I have a couple of them right after each other their backgrounds appear to "stick together". It appears this always happens when two consecutive lines have a background. A screenshot of the problem:

[image]

What I would actually expect:

[image]

(I made this image using an empty line with font size 1 and no line distance between the headers, but this is a very ugly workaround)

And a gif that shows the problem on normal text: [http://i.imgur.com/E4w0xmG.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/E4w0xmG.gifv)

Is there a way to get the backgrounds to separate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a white border to the paragraphs to get the correct amount of white space that you want after each heading.

1. As a preliminary step, enter a paragraph in each of the 3 heading styles and then another one in, for example, the style that you use for regular text.
2. Select all four paragraphs. (This step is important.)
3. Right-click **Heading 1** in the **Styles** gallery, and click **Modify**. Click **Format** > **Border**. If I want 6 points of space below the heading paragraph, I select **6 pt** as the width of the border, and set the color to white. I then select to apply both a bottom and middle border.
   [image: Settings in the Borders and Shading dialog box]

   The border replaces any space after setting on the paragraph style, so I clicked **Format** > **Paragraph** and set **After** to **0**.
4. Repeat step 3 for the **Heading 2** and **Heading 3** paragraph styles.

[image: Finished headings]